# 14.04 libreoffice not working

Tags: libreoffice

Today I suddenly found that LibreOffice will not open. It has worked fine for the past 2 years on ubuntu 14.04.

Have tried uninstalling, purging, and reinstalling, but still the same problem.

When I try to launch LibreOffice, there is a brief flicker, then nothing.
Will upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 help?

Comment: Have you tried opening it from a terminal (`libreoffice --writer` for example)? that may display some helpful error messages

Comment: I ended up upgrading to 16.04, and though the computer froze before completing, it now seems to work., and Libreoffice is now OK.

Comment: I think that the problem was in the kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty), it contains a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509). Newest kernel linux-image-3.13.0-123-generic includes correct fix.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading to 16.04, and though the computer froze before completing, it now seems to work., and Libreoffice is now OK.