# Java Plugin crashes on the latest kernel

Tags: kernel, java, jre

I know java npapi plugin is discontinued both by firefox and chrome, but I really need java to work.

So, installed Mozilla Build of Firefox, and kept it on a earlier version (51.0.1). Java has been working as expected. Java is Oracle java (Java(TM) Plug-in 11.131.2), with libnpjp2.so symlinked the usual way for many years;

Last week I updated to the new stable kernel 4.10.0-24 (no changes made to any configs) and the Java plugin just refuses to work.

If I boot with the previous kernel 4.10.0-22, the plugin works fine.

I cannot see any errors anywhere, although i was running firefox from konsole and looking at the output there.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: not really. can't find any errors. just won't work on the latest kernel.

Comment: If you can't "really" add more detail then we don't "really" know what you were trying to do and we can't "really" answer your question. How did you install Java and its browser plug-in? How did you convince Firefox to enable it even though it's black-listed? Which Java applet on which web site did you try to run?

Comment: ah, ok
i'm running "mozilla build of firefox", at version 51.0.1. installed it via a deb package from there.

Comment: sorry for that, "enter" is cutting my answers short.
so, java is oracle java, symlinked the usual way for many years;
if i run firefox with the new stable kernel 4.10.0-24, the plugin refuses to work;
if if reboot with previous kernel (no changes made) 4.10.0-22, the plugin works fine;
i cannot see any errors anywhere, although i was running firefox from konsole and looking at the output there ...
thanks

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update to let everyone know that the issue is fixed on kernel 4.10.0-26.

Answer (score 0):

I reported the same issue here with some details 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372559/java-plugin-crash-on-ubuntu-16-04-firefox-esr-52-2-0

Also coincidentally Eclipse seems to have problem recently where a bug report for the Linux kernel is referred [Eclipse Crashes with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-81-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic)

The life of the Java plugin is probably at its very end, but some will have problems where it is actually still in use.