# Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel release 3.13.0-121-generic: Eclipse crashes at start

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, eclipse

In the recent Ubuntu 14.04 update, Kernel release 3.13.0-121-generic was installed. Since then, eclipse crashes at start.
I had to manually roll back and to select
3.13.0-119-generic
in grub to work around the problem. Some further information to this may be found on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647525/eclipse-segmentation-fault

Update: I found this post:
[Eclipse Crashes with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-81-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic/928370#928370)

Will there be included a patch by Ubuntu in a subsequent Ubuntu 14.04 update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic contains a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509).

Be careful with kernel updates, which fix this vulnerability. Current patch breaks many java (sun/oracle and openjdk) applications. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772). The solution is to temporary reboot system with old kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty).

Ubuntu kernel developers [will prepare new patch in a few days](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-June/017507.html).

**UPDATE:** Latest updates (at least image-4.4.0-83-generic, linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic, linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic) fix this vulnerability and problems with user-space programs.