# Scilab 6.0.0 segmentation fault (core dumped) on start

Tags: segmentation-fault, scilab

I have Scilab 6.0.0 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it was working great until yesterday. I tried to execute the program via terminal (`./bin/scilab`) and I got the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I've already updated and upgraded ubuntu and this Scilab's version is the latest one. Looking for an answer to my problem I tried to run Scilab on a debug session in gdb and I got this:

```
> Running debug of Scilab [gdb]  :  gdb --args scilab-bin -debug gdb:
> /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libncurses.so.5:
> no version information available (required by gdb) gdb:
> /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libncurses.so.5:
> no version information available (required by gdb) GNU gdb (Ubuntu
> 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1 Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
> //gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you are free
> to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for
> details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu". Type "show
> configuration" for configuration details. For bug reporting
> instructions, please see: <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
> Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
> <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>. For help, type
> "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to
> "word"... Lendo símbolos de scilab-bin...(no debugging symbols
> found)...concluído. (gdb) run Starting program:
> /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/bin/scilab-bin -debug warning: the debug
> information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libtk8.5.so.debug" does
> not match "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libtk8.5.so"
> (CRC mismatch).
> 
> warning: the debug information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libtcl8.5.so.debug" does
> not match "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libtcl8.5.so"
> (CRC mismatch).
> 
> warning: the debug information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libhdf5.so.7.0.2.debug"
> does not match
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libhdf5.so.7" (CRC
> mismatch).
> 
> warning: the debug information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libfftw3.so.3.3.2.debug"
> does not match
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/libfftw3.so.3" (CRC
> mismatch).
> 
> warning: the debug information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libgfortran.so.3.0.0.debug"
> does not match
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libgfortran.so.3"
> (CRC mismatch).
> 
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db
> library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1". warning: the debug
> information found in
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libncurses.so.5.5.debug"
> does not match
> "/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist/libncurses.so.5"
> (CRC mismatch).
> 
> [New Thread 0x7fffea9fc700 (LWP 2267)] [New Thread 0x7fffdbfff700 (LWP
> 2268)] [New Thread 0x7fffe146f700 (LWP 2269)] [New Thread
> 0x7fffe136e700 (LWP 2270)] [New Thread 0x7fffe126d700 (LWP 2271)] [New
> Thread 0x7fffe116c700 (LWP 2272)] [New Thread 0x7fffbfdfd700 (LWP
> 2273)]
> 
> Thread 1 "scilab-bin" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007fffc500fe43 in ?? () (gdb) backtrace
> #0  0x00007fffc500fe43 in ?? ()
> #1  0x00007fffffffccd0 in ?? ()
> #2  0x00007fffc47ffca8 in ?? ()
> #3  0x00007fffffffcd18 in ?? ()
> #4  0x00007fffc48a8f38 in ?? ()
> #5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I'm just a regular user and I don't know how to proceed. I don't know if this is important, but I also have Windows 10 in this computer, but I think I didn't change anything on Windows or Ubuntu to cause this problem.

edit: I also used the `SCIVERBOSE=y ./bin/scilab` command and that's what I got:

```
SCILABBIN : scilab-bin
DISABLE_JAVA_DETECTION : 0
SCILAB_MODE : gui
OS : Linux
MODEL : x86_64
IS_SCILAB_BINARY : 1
SCI : /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab
SCIBIN : 
PATH : Scilab/./bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/alexandregsoares/bin:/home/alexandregsoares/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab/modules/scicos/
CLASSPATH : /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab/modules/core/jar/org.scilab.modules.core.jar
EGL_DRIVER : 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH : /home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab/bin:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab/lib/scilab/:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/share/scilab/lib64/scilab/:.:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/scilab:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/thirdparty/java//lib/amd64/:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/thirdparty/java//lib/amd64/server/:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/thirdparty/java//lib/amd64/native_threads/:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/home/alexandregsoares/Scilab/lib/thirdparty/redist
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Running `SCIVERBOSE=y ./bin/scilab` should  provide some higher-level debug information (from the wrapper script - rather than the binary executable) that may be helpful - especially the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CLASSPATH` outputs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, steeldriver. I edited my answer including the SCIVERBOSE command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this code in a terminal console before running your program:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xss1280k
```

Source:
[Eclipse Crashes with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-81-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic/927824#927824?newreg=a96882b126fc455e8d75f21eb11bee28)

Comment: Worked great even in this kernel version. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm in CentOS 7 for Scilab 6.0.0, thanks!

Comment: Not a  solution in Ubuntu 17.10.
It opens but it segfaults when I try:
A=rand(100,100); inv(A).

Answer (score 3):

It is known regression of 4.4.0-81-generic kernel. It affects many applications that use Java:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772 .
Boot with previous kernel version or wait for the future kernel release.

Comment: Booting with previous kernel version worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Please, tell us which kernel is working for you under which distribution. I have Ubuntu 17.10, I've tried:

linux-image-3.14.74-031474-generic, 
linux-image-4.3.6-040306-generic, 
linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic, 
linux-image-4.13.0-17-generic,
linux-image-4.14.0-041400-generic.
All of those did segfault when I tried to invert a 100x100 matrix with:

A=rand(100,100);
inv(A).