# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Apache Directory Studio

Tags: apache2, segmentation-fault

I am facing a problem:
For three years I have been using Apache Directory Studio without any problem, and suddenly, it doesn't launch. I tried to launch from terminal and the error output is:
*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*
I run a command:
ulimit -c unlimited;

but still same error.

I read a bit and figured out that I should debug and save the output into the logs. I read this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped), but did not understand.

1. Please help, if you know how to resolve the problem?
2. Please help and explain what commands should I run in order to save the output into the logs.

Thank you very much

Comment: What is your system and kernel version (`uname -a`)?

Comment: Linux talgat-HP-Pro-3400-Series-MT 4.4.0-82-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 20 15:22:28 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I suspect it's the same [kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772) that was identified here [Scilab 6.0.0 segmentation fault (core dumped) on start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928732/scilab-6-0-0-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-on-start) - try the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` fix described there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your apache Directory Studio got corrupted , you need to re-download the latest version 
and start using that one..

Follow below link for latest version download :--
http://directory.apache.org/studio/downloads.html

Comment: I deleted Apache directory, then downloaded from the link above, and un archived it. When I try to run same error output comes out.