# LibreOffice writer Crashes on Start

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, crash

I have been using LibreOffice writer without any trouble until today. With no warning it simply refuses to open any documents with writer. All other suites are working fine, I can open calc fine, but as soon as I try a text document, the whole thing crashes. If I start with Writer it gives me a splash screen and then nothing, not even a crash report.

No other issues with OS. I have Lubuntu with latest updates. Very old laptop but has never been slow enough to cause crashes

Comment: did you try to start libreoffice.writer from a terminal in order to see if you get some useful error message?

Comment: I did, that's what's puzzling. No output, good or bad. It simply launches the splash screen and then returns to prompt after program crashes. Where would the error logs be for libreoffice?

Comment: The problem may be with linux kernel -  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic (in Xenial) contains a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509) but break user-space programs. Have you tried with newest kernel update? I have linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic installed, and I can run `libreoffice --writer` normally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue on Arch linux (32bit xfce) https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227597

I've managed to **solve it by turning off Java in Libreoffice**>

*First, start Libreoffice, click on Tools, click on options and under Libreoffice section click on Advanced. Deselect "Use a Java runtime environment"* and problem solved.

I don't think this a good solution, but considering I don't use Java in Libreoffice it's good enough for me.

Comment: You rock! This fixed the issue and is my accepted answer since it had the details. Even though there is likely a better answer to fix LO with java this will do for now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Why is LO using Java in the first place?

Comment: This is a known issue in the kernel/JVM code. [Bug #1699772](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1699772) tracks the issue. Until this is properly fixed, the best workaround is to turn off java in libreoffice, indeed.

Comment: Same symptoms as OP. I think a reinstalled Libreoffice 3 times, deleted the profile files 42 times, and this is the only bullet proof solution. Thank you !