# Ubuntu 17.04; LibreOffice crashes on start

Tags: java, libreoffice

More or less the same problem as [LibreOffice writer Crashes on Start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927859/libreoffice-writer-crashes-on-start): starting last week, LibreOffice crashes every time I try to start it. In the beginning it was just Writer, now no module starts anymore. The splash screen comes, the program loads halfway, then closes with no error.

The answer to the above mentioned question might work for me too, but how can I turn off Java, if the program won't start at all?

Comment: What is the output when running the program from the terminal?

Comment: Please open a terminal and execute the command `lowriter` - this will attempt to start libre office writer, and perhaps display some error messages.  The you can edit your question, and post the error messages into the question.

Comment: Starting "lowriter" from the terminal has the same results as starting "libreoffice": The splash screen appears, stays for a while, the orange progress bar appears and runs until it gets to a position under the b of "LibreOffice". There its stalls, the process crashes, the splash screen disappears, the terminal adds another line with a command prompt. Then Ubuntu gives out an error message "The application soffice.bin was unexpecedly terminated" (in French) with the details "ExecutablePath etc." That's all.

Comment: Oops, Ubuntu's just added lines to the error message. I cannot copy the text but anyway, it's way too long to post. Made screenshots so I can provide details if I know which ones are helpful. 3 things strike me: 1. "Segfault happened at: 0xb3b1e905 <__GI___libc_malloc+197>:   test   %eax,%eax" (I don't understad a word), 2. "SegvReason      reading unknown VMA" (ditto) and 3. "UnreportableReason  "(my summary of French text:) the version of package "libepoxy0" is obsolete. What should I do?

Comment: It may be kernel issue. Have you tried to start Libreoffice Writer after installing all latest updates?

Comment: Yes. Last update less than an hour ago, same results before and after rebooting the machine.

Comment: @HGerbig can you see if maybe some corrupt user settings are causing the crash?  With LO closed, rename ~/.config/libreoffice to something like ~/.config/libreoffice-save and then try starting.  If it still crashes, you can restore your previous settings folder.  If it doesn't crash, then you have to go through re-configuring your settings and then maybe it would narrow down where the crash was occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently suffering the same issue, it was happen after i upgrade the kernel 4.10.0-19 to 4.10.0.37 while JRE was needed to run Zotero in libreoffice.

In the last, i tried to remove the newer kernel and it came to be normal.
by running:

```
sudo mv /boot/*10.0-37*   /media/*
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
reboot
```