# Segmantation fault, during Eclipse and LiClipse starting

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, 32-bit, segmentation-fault

Neither Eclipse nor LiCLipse cannot be started. Both of them start with the **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** problem. 
I try to reinstall with eclipse-installer and from packages, but none of them work. 
Installer starting with a segmentation fault. :(:(:( 
I try to update Java but it can not help me. 
GDB log file:

```
gdb ./eclipse-inst 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./eclipse-inst...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/****/Letöltések/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
process 26815 is executing new program: /home/****/Letöltések/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xb650ab40 (LWP 26821)]
[New Thread 0xb5bffb40 (LWP 26824)]
[New Thread 0xb51ffb40 (LWP 26825)]
[New Thread 0x713d9b40 (LWP 26838)]

Thread 1 "eclipse-inst" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb1d66d27 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb1d66d27 in ?? ()
#1  0xb1d5c419 in ?? ()
#2  0xb40585bf in JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#3  0xb41f6ed9 in os::os_exception_wrapper(void (*)(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*), JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#4  0xb4056b8f in JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#5  0xb402f456 in InstanceKlass::call_class_initializer_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#6  0xb402f856 in InstanceKlass::initialize_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#7  0xb402fba1 in InstanceKlass::initialize(Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#8  0xb402fa43 in InstanceKlass::initialize_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#9  0xb402fba1 in InstanceKlass::initialize(Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#10 0xb42d1939 in initialize_class(Symbol*, Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#11 0xb42d8dda in Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#12 0xb409873c in JNI_CreateJavaVM () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#13 0xb7fcf92b in startJavaJNI (libPath=0x8050078 "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so", vmArgs=0x80bde60, progArgs=0x80eacc0, 
    jarFile=0x8050fb0 "/home/****/Letöltések/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar") at ../eclipseJNI.c:367
#14 0xb7fd10cf in startJavaVM (libPath=0x8050078 "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so", vmArgs=0x80bde60, progArgs=0x80eacc0, 
    jarFile=0x8050fb0 "/home/****/Letöltések/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar") at ../eclipseNix.c:174
#15 0xb7fca1bc in _run (argc=3, argv=0x804e858, vmArgs=0x8050068) at ../eclipse.c:652
#16 0xb7fc9a5e in run (argc=3, argv=0x804e858, vmArgs=0x0) at ../eclipse.c:471
#17 0x080491ce in main (argc=14, argv=0x804e858) at ../eclipseMain.c:215
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in linux kernel - linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic contains a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509).

Be careful with kernel updates, which fix this vulnerability. Current patch breaks many java (sun/oracle and openjdk) applications. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772). The solution is to temporary reboot system with old kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty).

Ubuntu kernel developers [will prepare new patch in a few days](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-June/017507.html).

**UPDATE:** Latest updates (at least image-4.4.0-83-generic, linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic, linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic) fix this vulnerability and problems with user-space programs.