# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - linux kernel problem

Tags: xubuntu, java, eclipse, segmentation-fault

Can someone help me to fix issue with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" on Ubuntu 16.04. Whatever program I am trying to install (e.g. Aptana Studio 3; liclipse_4.0.0) I get this error when running executable file:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I've read about this error on Internet and answers says that "A segmentation fault is almost always due to a bug in the program where it occurs". I found it most unlikely that all programs I am trying to install have a bug. It must be something wrong with my system.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a program you are trying to install, and how you are doing it?

Comment: It is a bug, but you need to tell us what you did or what program you are doing to get that error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault or similar.

Comment: I've tired to install: Aptana Studio 3. liclipse_4.0.0. On both I got the same error when trying to run executable file.

Comment: Each time when I reboot I got this error messages popping out: "System program problem detected". 3 windows with this message pops out. Looks like its one window per program that I've installed, and which is not able to start up. Moreover I am loosing Internet connection from time to time without any reason. I thought it is Internet provider's fault, but I am able to re-connect when I reboot. Also other person using the same router in my flat does not have network issues at the time I loose connection. Seems like my system is messed up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Crashes with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-81-generic](/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in linux kernel - linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic (in Trusty) and linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic (in Xenial) contains a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509).

Be careful with kernel updates, which fix this vulnerability. Current patch breaks many java (sun/oracle and openjdk) applications. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772). The solution is to temporary reboot system with old kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty / linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic in Xenial).

Ubuntu kernel developers [will prepare new patch in a few days](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-June/017507.html).

**UPDATE:** Latest updates (at least image-4.4.0-83-generic, linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic, linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic) fix this vulnerability and problems with user-space programs.

Comment: How do I install "linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic"? On: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.13.0-121.170   I see 3 files: "linux_3.13.0.orig.tar.gz", "linux_3.13.0-121.170.diff.gz", "linux_3.13.0-121.170.dsc". Which one should I install? My current kernel version is: "4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:15:00 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux".

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: On 16.04 you should try `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic` and `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic`. Then reboot with 79 kernel.

Comment: I did as advised. Rebooted and now I am able to lunch all applications previously unavailable. Many thanks for help. I was about to re-install system but saw you answer - just on time :) Pity I cannot vote for your answer.

Comment: @zwornik. Nice to hear! Do not forget to install linux-image-generic after some  weeks. But if you are using home PC you can stay on 79 kernel as long as you want. It's very unlikely, that your PC may be hacked.

Comment: @zwornik If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @terdon Done. Thanks for remark. I did not know about this option. I've tried to vote for this answer but I am not allowed.

Comment: @zwornik yeah, voting is a little strange. You need to have participated a little before you can vote (the idea is that we want votes from people using the site not random passers by). It only takes 15 reputation points (so 3 upvotes ona  question or 1.5 on an answer) though, son it isn't too hard. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Latest updates (at least image-4.4.0-83-generic, linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic, linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic) fix this vulnerability and problems with user-space programs. You can install latest kernel with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-tools-generic`.